# How to allow space in function parameter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

How can the following code work correctly for each of the parameters to equal true when there is a white space between two words with the following line?

```
custom = detector.CustomObjects(cell phone=True, car=True)
```

This is from the ImageAI library and below is the example:

```
"""
There are 80 possible objects that you can detect with the
ObjectDetection class, and they are as seen below.

    person,   bicycle,   car,   motorcycle,   airplane,
    bus,   train,   truck,   boat,   traffic light,   fire hydrant,   stop_sign,
    parking meter,   bench,   bird,   cat,   dog,   horse,   sheep,   cow,   elephant,   bear,   zebra,
    giraffe,   backpack,   umbrella,   handbag,   tie,   suitcase,   frisbee,   skis,   snowboard,
    sports ball,   kite,   baseball bat,   baseball glove,   skateboard,   surfboard,   tennis racket,
    bottle,   wine glass,   cup,   fork,   knife,   spoon,   bowl,   banana,   apple,   sandwich,   orange,
    broccoli,   carrot,   hot dog,   pizza,   donot,   cake,   chair,   couch,   potted plant,   bed,
    dining table,   toilet,   tv,   laptop,   mouse,   remote,   keyboard,   cell phone,   microwave,
    oven,   toaster,   sink,   refrigerator,   book,   clock,   vase,   scissors,   teddy bear,   hair dryer,
    toothbrush.

To detect only some of the objects above, you will need to call the CustomObjects function and set the name of the
object(s) yiu want to detect to through. The rest are False by default. In below example, we detected only chose detect only person and dog.
"""
custom = detector.CustomObjects(person=True, dog=True)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why does it have to be a space in a parameter-name? Can't you just do `cell_phone`? Or is that taken from a dictionary that you're passing in?

Comment: @Torxed - the variable is taken from the dictionary and cannot be changed as it's through an imported library.

Comment: I'd say clean the dicionary first, do a `for key in list(dictionary.keys()): dictionary[key.replace(' ', '_')] = dictionary[key]`.

Comment: How can variables contain space?

Comment: @Austin I'd say, they can't. But this feels like one of those time someone with deeper knowledge of Python will swoop in and bust my world view wide open..

Answer (score 3):

Python's syntax requires a keyword argument to be a valid identifier, which does not permit whitespace. You'll need to unpack an explicit dictionary instead.

```
custom = detector.CustomObjects(**{"cell phone": True, "car": True})
```

As a demonstration that it is entirely up to the callable to accept or reject `cell phone` (rather than a matter of language semantics):

```
>>> def foo(**kwargs):
...   for k, v in kwargs.items():
...     print("Key: {}".format(k))
...     print("Value: {}".format(v))
...
>>> foo(**{"cell phone": 9})
Key: cell phone
Value: 9
```

---

Note that, documentation aside, the [actual argument defined by `CustomObjects`](https://github.com/OlafenwaMoses/ImageAI/blob/571c309319f58650848123513b8f1adce90396c1/imageai/Detection/__init__.py#L544) is `cell_phone`, not `cell phone`. If a value for `cell_phone` is passed, the `dict` returned by the method contains the string `cell phone` as a key.

Comment: I'm interested to see how this works around `TypeError: 'cell phone' is an invalid keyword argument for X`? How do you even define something to allow a white-space declaration of either a parameter or a variable? You can't do `def X(cell phone=False)`? Unless you're doing `def(**kwargs)` that is. In which case, I don't see the point of this parameter being passed as separate entities. o0

Comment: If `CustomObjects` uses `**kwargs` to receive arbitrary keyword arguments, then it is only limited to what can be used as a valid dictionary key. It sounds like the class, however, is explicitly rejecting `cell phone` as a valid argument, i.e. it has a white list of arguments that it is looking for and it raises a `TypeError` for (instead of ignoring) everything else.

Comment: Here is a link to the ImageAI library I am using. The cell phone text is displayed here. https://imageai.readthedocs.io/en/latest/detection/index.html?highlight=custom

Comment: The documentation is misleading. See the update for a link to the actual code that defines `cell_phone` as the parameter, not `cell phone`.